# how to htaccess make dynamic url to static url

Tags: redirect

I have a URL like:

https://www.example.com/3889/content-title.html?post_action=dislike

to:

https://www.example.com/3889/content-title.html

301 redirect  Thank you so much.. (wordpress)

i need 301 redirect this link webmaster tools have problems ''Alternative page with correct canonical tag''